# How do bash loops work precisely?

Tags: bash, for, brace-expansion

```
for i in {0..999999999}; do echo "hi"; done
```

takes a long time to write it's output, as if all the `echo`s are first executed and then sent to `stdout`. The effect is even more pronounced with `cowfortune` instead of `echo` and makes terminal buffering less likely to be the issue.

So what precisely happens when I execute the above command, step by step? And why is the delay?

Comment: I've just tested your command and there was no delay.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I added a few 9s and tested it again. At the revised state, it takes my i7 about 15 seconds to print anything.

Comment: Can you add `time` in front of it and share the time values? So, `time for i in {0..999999999}; do echo "hi"; done`

Comment: [Related](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

Comment: Surely something strange is happening? Had to kill BASH when it reached about 13GB after a couple of minutes. For a reduced {0..1000000}, I got
real 0m8.254s
user 0m4.902s
sys 0m3.348s

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ordinary `for` loops always iterate over a static set of strings. This is regardless of whether the strings are generated by brace expansions or by filename globbing patterns, or some other expansion of a variable or command substitution, etc.

For your `for` loop, you generate the strings to loop over using a brace expansion.  That brace expansion has to be expanded before the first iteration of the loop can run.  Since you generate such a huge list of words (each one of the one billion whole numbers in the range 0 to 999999999) this would likely take some time (and probably more than 8 gigabytes of RAM).

If you really need to do that sort of iteration in `bash`, use an arithmetic `for` loop instead:

```bsh
for (( i=0; i <= 999999999; ++i )); do echo hi; done
```

... or solve the particular issue in some other way

```bsh
yes hi | head -n 1000000000
```

... or consider using almost any other language for your task at hand, as shell scripting languages are rarely efficient for this sort of task.

Comment: Or cause the OS to freeze...

Comment: 90 % of those billion numbers are 9 digits long, so, stored as strings which the shell words are, that should already be about 8 GB, I think. Plus a few GB for bookkeeping, I suppose. In any case, on my 4 GB (+ 8 GB swap) system, it just fails with "bash: brace expansion: failed to allocate memory for 1000000000 elements"...