# Bash print command with number

Tags: bash, scripting

Good Day!
I'm just a beginner and I want to dive into bash scripting.
I want to create a script that do a command, and in this command I want to try multiple numbers from **001-999 in each time** |
e.g.
`python3 tool.py -n 12345 -e <numbers from 001-999 in each time>`
thanks

Comment: An easy way is going to be a for loop, which you can search for examples here or online, or go to [tldp.org bash programming intro](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html) which has examples.

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```bsh
seq -w 1 999 | xargs -I {} python3 tool.py -n 12345 -e {}
```

This would execute your Python script once for each number outputted by `seq`.  The `seq` utility (part of GNU coreutils), the way it's used here, would output numbers from 1 to 999 where each number is zero-filled to equal width.

Note that there's not very much that the `bash` shell itself is doing here, apart from setting up the pipe between the `seq` and `xargs` utilities.

Would you want to do it purely in `bash`, then you could probably use an arithmetic `for` loop and `printf` to format the numbers.

```bsh
for (( num = 1; num <= 999; ++num )); do
    printf -v znum '%.3d' "$num"
    python3 tool.py -n 12345 -e "$znum"
done
```

The variable `znum` holds the zero-filled three-digit variant of `$num` in each iteration in the loop above.

A common way to make shorter loops in `bash` is by using `for` with a brace expansion, as in

```bsh
for num in {001..999}; do
    python3 tool.py -n 12345 -e "$num"
done
```

I think this is perfectly fine if you remember a few things:

1. Older releases of the `bash` shell, like the default release of the shell used on macOS, would not zero-fill the numbers.  You would have to do something similar to the way I used `znum` earlier.
2. The shell would expand the brace expansion and keep the expanded list in memory before starting the first iteration.  For this example, with 999 numbers, this would use up somewhere around 4 Kb of memory.  For larger lists, this may be unfeasible and slow.  See e.g. [How do bash loops work precisely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/639423)
3. The `bash` shell does not allow the use of variables in brace expansions.

Comment: that's great thank you. what if I want to make it return success value only by setting a word if it's exist that's mean success

Comment: @iis2h I don't know what your Python script is doing or how it decides return success or not, and I don't know what you mean by setting a word or what it means that it exists.  None of these things were part of the original question. If you have further questions, then please ask a new question.

Comment: In bash (and some others) a `python3 tool.py -n 12345 -e {001..999}` seems to be easier than a loop. @they

Comment: @ImHere Yes, if you want to call the script with all those strings in one go. I believe this may depend on one's interpretation of the question.

Comment: `for num in {001..999}; do python3 tool.py -n 12345 "$num"; done`

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Yes, that's how many people do loops in `bash`, but it has two problems; 1) Older releases does not do zero filling of the numbers, and 2) it requires the shell to expand tho whole list before iterating over it, which is inelegant and wasteful, especially for larger lists.

Comment: @they I wouldn’t be all that concerned about 999 items. If the bounds were parameters / variables, _that_ would be a different story for sure. But this is safely in the “constant realm”. (As for older releases, nothing in the question requests support for them.)

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek I'm just trying to cater for more users than the one posing the question. There will be people out there that foolishly think we know what we're doing, and then they take the brace expansion and try to loop ten million times with it on macOS (a fairly common Unix, with a `bash` that does not support zero filling of integers in brace expansions), and then they wonder why it fails and why it consumes so much memory. I will edit and mention the brace expand loop when I get time to, including caveats.

Comment: `python3 tool.py -n 12345 -e {001..999}` would be the same as `python3 tool.py -n 12345 -e 001 002 003 ... 999`, and depending on how the script parses command line args, it could take `001` as the option-argument to `-e`, and the rest as non-option command line arguments. In any case, one invocation with several args can often be different from several invocations with just one arg.